# Updating an array in controller to store user input from Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, controller, custom-controller, inputtext, array

I need to store input from user in controller so it can be used for calculations.

To do this I am using an array, to get input in the controller.

But getting issue:
**Subscript is invalid because list is empty**

I have tried initializing array in the controller in static block, controller and get section but getting the same issue.

Controller:

```
    public with sharing class TestControllerForIssue{

  public String [] testArray{get; set;}

    public void doSomething(){
        System.debug('Started doSomething()');
        System.debug('testArray[0]=' + testArray[0]);
    }

    public TestControllerForIssue(){
        testArray = new String[5];
    }

    }
```

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page controller="TestControllerForIssue">
    <apex:form >
            <apex:commandButton value="CallAPI" action="{!doSomething}"/>
            <br/>
            <apex:pageBlock id="productData">   
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="text-align: center">Test Value</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><apex:inputText value="{!testArray[0]}"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Where/When do you receive this error?

Comment: I see it on the VF page when it is run on the Salesforce orf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because you have just initialized the array mentioning what should be the `size` of the `array`. Hence it will contain 5 null values, in order for you to use that array, you have to initialize the elements in the array.

In your controller's constructor, you have to add new instances of `string`, which then can be binded to `visualforce` page.

So your constructor would be

```
public TestControllerForIssue(){
    testArray = new List<String>{'','','','',''}
}
```

Comment: This is not completely correct. `testArray = new String[5];` will initialize the array. It's still fine not to have a value in it. So if you access the element say `testArray[3]`, it will give you `null`.

Comment: @Jayant Yup my bad, just observed it in the debug log, corrected it. Thanks for the observation.